# c# mvc validate form before ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I try to validate the form on the page /order/create, before ajax request

```
@model rentcar2.Models.mOrderSnapshot
...
<form id="order">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fam)
<form>
....    
$('#test').click(function () {
   if ($("#order").valid()) {
      alert(1);
   } else { alert(2); }
   alert(3);
});
```

But after Alert 1, 3 I get redirect to /order/create?fam=value(model.Fam)

I just to validate inputs and show invalids, why I get redirect?

Comment: Why don't use `jQuery.validate` ? Is included in MVC app by default

Comment: And how? How can I start validate process when I want?

Comment: What is your element with `id="test"` - you are not cancelling its default action!

Comment: And if your getting `alert(1)` then it means its valid, so why are you expecting to 'show invalids' (what ever you mean by that)?

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to use unobstrusive `jQuery.validate` plugin. It's the best way to make form client validation, and it's included in default `MVC.net Application`. This is an example :

```
@model rentcar2.Models.mOrderSnapshot
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fam)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fam)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

(`~/bundles/jqueryval` is added by default in MVC routes, but maybe you have to add it and download `jQuery.validate` with nuget package)

Don't forget to add some `DataAnnotations` on your ViewModel too for example :

```
public class mOrderSnapshot {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Fam { get; set; }
}
```

There are many `DataAnnotations` availables, and you can also create them by yourself, check the web.

If you want more informations about unobstrusive jQuery validation take a look to :
https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/

**EDIT :** You can also trigger manually a validation process using :

```
$('#myForm').valid();
```

And for a specified element :

```
$('#myForm').validate().element("#Fam");
```

Source : http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/#element

Comment: How can I start validate process without submit?

Comment: I updated answer but try to make a more clearly question specifying your really need

Comment: You never call `validate()` if using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why ?

Comment: Because that is already been initialized by the plugin. If you want to test if the form is valid then you use `if ($('form').valid()) { ...`

Comment: Yes I try to use $('#myForm').validate() but it doesnt work, but $('#myForm').validate().element("#Fam") - work!

Answer (score 1):

Use preventDefault to stop button to do it's default action.

```
 $('#test').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       if ($("#order").valid()) {
          alert(1);
       } else { alert(2); }
       alert(3);
    });
```